# ActionBarSherlock - List

Tags: android

I have an application for android news, it has splash screen after a list of news where you can access the news. I am using the Action Bar, but as I wanted other versions of android would use, I applied ActionBarSherlock, but when I try to access the list of news the app does not work, entirely, but that's the only problem,  before to add the it worked ActionBarSherlock: Below is the code:

Thank you ever so much, if anyone want more details about my question, please tell me here or 
Facebook: mardoqueu567@hotmail.com
gmail: mdq767@gmail.com

public class ListActivity extends SherlockActivity {

```
RSSFeed feed;
ListView lv;
CustomListAdapter adapter;
String feedLink;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.feed_list);

    // set the feed link for refresh
    feedLink = new SplashActivity().RSSFEEDURL;

    // Get feed form the file
    feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");

    // Initialize the variables:
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

    // Set an Adapter to the ListView
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
    //lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set on item click listener to the ListView
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // actions to be performed when a list item clicked
            int pos = arg2;

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,
                    DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.refresh_option:
        refreshList(item);
        return (true);

    case R.id.about_option:
        Toast.makeText(this, "RSS Reader!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return (true);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void refreshList(final MenuItem item) {
    /* Attach a rotating ImageView to the refresh item as an ActionView */
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_refresh,
            null);

    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(),
            R.anim.refresh_rotate);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    iv.startAnimation(rotation);

    item.setActionView(iv);

    // trigger feed refresh:
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DOMParser tmpDOMParser = new DOMParser();
            feed = tmpDOMParser.parseXml(feedLink);

            ListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (feed != null && feed.getItemCount() > 0) {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        item.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                        item.setActionView(null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// List adapter class
class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public CustomListAdapter(ListActivity activity) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        // Set the total list item count
        return feed.getItemCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Inflate the item layout and set the views
        View listItem = convertView;
        int pos = position;
        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        // Initialize the views in the layout
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.date);

        // Set the views in the layout
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(feed.getItem(pos).getImage(), iv);
        tvTitle.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getTitle());
        tvDate.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getDate());

        return listItem;
    }

}
```

}

### LogCat

```
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:389)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:162)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.td.rssreader.DetailActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(DetailActivity.java:56)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:64)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:164)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:393)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2913)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4793)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
10-10 18:32:14.789: E/AndroidRuntime(18245):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 18:32:14.959: D/dalvikvm(18245): GC_CONCURRENT freed 578K, 12% free 6726K/7559K, paused 19ms+41ms, total 162ms
10-10 18:32:15.529: D/HostStatisticManager(18245): netstack: DNS Host Prioritization is: ON, Version: 5.0.1
10-10 18:32:15.529: V/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/host_resolver_helper/host_resolver_helper.cc:66: [1010/183215:INFO:host_resolver_helper.cc(66)] DNSPreResolver::Init got hostprovider:0x51cad010
10-10 18:32:15.529: V/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/base/host_resolver_impl.cc:1510: [1010/183215:INFO:host_resolver_impl.cc(1510)] HostResolverImpl::SetPreresolver preresolver:0x51c9fac0
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/(18245): external/chromium/net/socket/tcp_fin_aggregation_factory.cc: libtcpfinaggr.so successfully loaded
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/(18245): external/chromium/net/socket/tcp_fin_aggregation_factory.cc,: TCP Fin Aggregation initializing method was found in libtcpfinaggr.so
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/TCPFinAggregation(18245): netstack: TCPFinAggregation is 1, Version 5.0.1
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/TCPFinAggregation(18245): system property net.tcp.fin.aggregation.wait was set, value: 20
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/TCPFinAggregation(18245): system property net.tcp.fin.aggregation.close was set, value: 300
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/TCPFinAggregation(18245): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON, (TCPFinAggregation), Version 5.0.1
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/TCPFinAggregation(18245): Failed to get network status! received ret: -2
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/Socket_Pool(18245): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/Socket_Pool(18245): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/Socket_Pool(18245): netstack: CloseUnusedSockets is ON
10-10 18:32:15.569: D/Socket_Pool(18245): netstack: system net.statistics value: 0
10-10 18:32:15.579: D/(18245): external/chromium/net/http/http_getzip_factory.cc: libgetzip.so successfully loaded
10-10 18:32:15.579: D/(18245): external/chromium/net/http/http_getzip_factory.cc,: GETzip initializing method was found in libgetzip.so
10-10 18:32:15.579: D/netstack(18245): netstack: Request Priority is ON
10-10 18:32:15.579: D/(18245): netstack: Getzip is: ON, Version: 5.0.1
10-10 18:32:15.649: V/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:52: [1010/183215:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(52)] StatHubCreateHostResPlugin initializing...
10-10 18:32:15.659: V/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:57: [1010/183215:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(57)] StatHubCreateHostResPlugin lib loaded
10-10 18:32:15.659: V/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:63: [1010/183215:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(63)] StatHubCreateHostResPlugin plugin connected
10-10 18:32:15.659: V/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/http/http_cache.cc:1168: [1010/183215:INFO:http_cache.cc(1168)] HttpCache::OnBackendCreated HostStat created
10-10 18:32:15.659: E/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [1010/183215:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.td.rssreader isn't supported.
10-10 18:32:15.669: V/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:73: [1010/183215:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(73)] netstack: Failed to find symbols in plugin: libdnshostprio.so
10-10 18:32:15.689: E/chromium(18245): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [1010/183215:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.td.rssreader isn't supported.
10-10 18:32:17.339: W/webcore(18245): skip viewSizeChanged as w is 0
10-10 18:32:17.339: W/webcore(18245): skip viewSizeChanged as w is 0
10-10 18:32:17.349: W/webcore(18245): skip viewSizeChanged as w is 0
```

Comment: Please give a bit less code, just what's necessary! Why don't you use the support library, and ActionBarActivity? And please, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) doc about good questions!

Comment: I am terrible sorry, mate, I am not good at making questions, I perfected the question. It improved?

Comment: What's the 56th line of the code? This `feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");`? If yep, I the casting does not works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, mate. I will try something about that

Comment: That's your 56th line? If I'm right, you cannot put everything into Bundles, so that'll be the problem.

Comment: mate, I'm confused, what should I to do?

Comment: What do you want to do? You'd like to pass that `RSS Feed` object to this Activity?

Comment: Before to add the ActionBarSherlock, the app working very well, I don't know where exactly is the problem :( , you'd like to see all the project?